# relation "geo_dominio" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a schema called **georeferenciacion_uno** and on that schema I have for example this table **geo_dominio**.

Working with eclipse I could connect with my DB without problem but I couldn´t make a simple query like "select * from geo_dominio", because I always get the next answer:

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "geo_dominio"  does not exist**

I tried all this sentences:

- "select * from geo_dominio"
- "select * from GEO_DOMINIO"
- "select * from \"geo_dominio\""
- "select * from \"GEO_DOMINIO\""
- "select * from georeferenciacion_uno.geo_dominio"  --->    but here I got that answer: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: **schema** "georeferenciacion_uno" does not exist

Then I decided make that query directly on pgAdmin with next results:

ERROR:  schema "georeferenciacion_uno" does not exist

then I realised that the error is not on my script of Eclipse. I am doing something bad but I still don´t know what it is.

I can not change the database or table names because they are working from years ago...

I've looked for the solution of that problem here but people find their solution just with one of this possibilities, depending tipically of case sensitive or using double quotes as I tried.

If someone could help me I would thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to check:

1. Are you connected to the right database?  That it isn't finding the schema suggests you may not be.  To test this try:

   ```
     SELECT current_database();
   ```
2. I assume your schema is all lowercase?  If not, it will be treated as lowercase unless double quoted.
3. Once your fully qualified relational name query (the last one) is working, you may want to

   ```
     SET search_path=georeferenciacion_uno,public;
   ```

   so it finds the tables in that schema without the schema name.

My guess though is maybe you are connected to the wrong database.